# sinatra app on localhost via unicorn: syntax error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, localhost, unicorn

I have a Sinatra app that I continually upgrade (local only, at the moment). Problem being that I know nothing at all about Ruby — my friend made me the app and it's worked beautifully for over almost a year.

To see the site on localhost, I do this:

```
bundle exec unicorn -l 9000
```

I don't understand this, haven't needed to. I know I'm using the unicorn gem to run the app directed at port 9000 (due to an old printer conflict).

Today, I get this error:

```
in `evaluate': compile error (SyntaxError)
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
```

which refers to line 16 of my gem file, the sinatra-contrib gem:

```
gem "sinatra-contrib", require: "sinatra/reloader"
```

I've never had this error before. Haven't ever touched the gem file, and it's been working for a year. The only thing I can think I've done recently that may have affected my environment is installing a gemset called Wordless:

```
rvm use 1.8.7@wordless --create --default && gem install therubyracer sprockets compass coffee-script thor yui-compressor && rvm wrapper 1.8.7@wordless wordless compass ruby
```

I'd appreciate insights, and hopefully I can start to learn a thing or two about managing ruby gems. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You were using Ruby 1.9 before. The line you referenced is in 1.9 format, which Ruby 1.8 does not understand.

When you installed Wordless you said:

```
rvm use 1.8.7@wordless --create --default
```

This made Ruby 1.8.7 your default interpreter. To switch back to whatever you used before do:

```
rvm list rubies
```

And then:

```
rvm use [the 1.9.x you found in the list above] --default
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I was blind and now I see a bit of dirt underneath the chair behind the door. Cheers.